# Как в PyQt вывести HTML c подсветкой некоторых тегов?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Делаю программу с использованием PyQt5. Одна из функций - вывод HTML с подсветкой некоторых тегов разными цветами. Каждая новая строка обрабатывается и добавляется через .append. Понятное дело, поле класса QTextEdit мне не подходит, так как требуется вывод чистого HTML. Выход - применение полей класса QPlainTextEdit. Но тут проблема в применении цвета - теги font я уже не могу использовать, QPlainTextEdit предполагает вывод чисто текста без применения цвета. Экранирование тегов в QTextEdit не лучшая идея. Применение цвета ко всему полю тоже совсем не подходит.
Как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: `Понятное дело, поле класса QTextEdit мне не подходит, так как требуется вывод чистого HTML.` а что мешает в html вывести html и подсветить нужные теги?

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, что вы подразумеваете? Экранирование?

Comment: Знаю, что это возможно, но тут нужно погуглить и лучше просто на тему html, без всяких питонов и qt, уверен сразу найдете ответ

Comment: Да я понимаю, что можно средствами html. Просто не хочется лепить дополнительный код, который бы вставлял вместо тегов всевозможные  &lt; &gt;... Меня как раз интересует решение с помощью PyQt

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в Qt есть специальное решение для отображения html в html, попробуйте сами поискать решение

Comment: Для подсветки тегов можно использовать класс `QSyntaxHighlighter` в котором можно прописать необходимые правила подсветки. Далее вы устаналиваете `QSyntaxHighlighter` на  `QPlainTextEdit.document` и на выходе получаете подсвеченный код.